# i have to refresh an activity , but these refresh is bit complicated

Tags: java, android

i have 2 Activities A and B , "A" hold a list of certain songs category , while i click on these list its start new activity "B" and load a new list of songs based on user choice , if user made another click on the list in Activity B its start to play the song. When user click on back button , its goes back to Activity "A" but the player still continue in background. My actual problem starts here , when user again clicks on other category from Activity "A" (while the song is still playing in background) it does not reloading the new category in Activity B but showing old list . How i overcome these . i need help

ACTIVITY A onclick

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String webpage = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.link))
                    .getText().toString();
            String titles = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                    .getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class); 
            intent.putExtra("webpage_key",webpage);
            intent.putExtra("title_key",titles);
    startActivity(intent); 
    }
```

Comment: start that activity b as new task

Comment: Post some code so we can help. The intents you are using would be particularly useful.

Comment: which method in activity B do you use to get the info and update the listview?

Comment: sax parser to parse the data and put them to list view

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement that using listView ? If yes, did you use this method in your Activity A ?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Comment: How did let Activity B know what kind of music the user did select ? Did you use an Intent ?

Comment: Did you pass it with onClick or onItemClick ?

Comment: sorry its onitemclick i pass intent to activity B

Comment: Good, you should put some extra data in your intent to let Activity B know what kind of music has been chosen. Did you do it ?

Comment: Yes , and thank you  , i found the solution also . In my code i was saving current state of activity B  , And when user comes with a new click , its only loads the last saved state . there was a IF condition which only allow new list loading when current_state==null . Because of that IF condtion i was unable to load new list in Activity B listview and now its done